# What is a simple way to add my Twitter Stream onto a website?

Tags: wordpress, twitter

Is there an easy way to use the Twitter API to have my twitter feed on a separate blog page? I tried using the basic twitter widget, with different width & height, but the font sizes are frankly quite small and it doesn't let you edit any of it.

After a bit more searching, I haven't been any closer to finding a solution. Is there an easy process to accomplish this?

I'm using Wordpress as well, so a Wordpress plugin solution would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just used Twitter-Tools ( http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-tools/ ) to integrate my wordpress site with Twitter.  I'm only using the portion that tweets my new blog posts, but I think it claims to do what you want.

Comment: I also use Twitter-Tools but only to show my tweets on my blog.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following solution with WordPress, it allowed me to customize the look and feel, might be helpful to you.

[Integrate Twitter Into Your Web Site Using PHP](http://farinspace.com/twitter-feed-website-integration/)